# Configure Meld Encoding to CP-1252

Tags: encoding, meld

Is it possible to configure Meld to open diff/merge files with encoding CP-1252 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should configure it by setting the gsettings key 'detect-encodings' for the wanted encodings.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.meld detect-encodings "['UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1252', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"
```

Comment: May be you know how to do the same on Windows?

Comment: I found it:  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\GSettings\org\gnome\meld]
"detect-encodings"="['WINDOWS-1251', 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"

Comment: Awesome. This should be in the GUI I think.

Comment: What about WSL? I updated my gsettings in WSL, but it didn't help. I am outputting the video to VcXsrv. I do not have a GSettings in my registry because Meld is installed in Ubuntu 18.04 WSL.

Comment: To fix my problem in WSL, I converted the file encoding from ISO-8859 to UTF-8 using the iconv command as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/839755/meld-shows-output-in-unreadable-alphabet-japanese-chinese

Comment: @Jk. Not sure why you put `WINDOWS-1251` rather than "1252".

Answer (score 0):

If you can´t find, you can create it.

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\GSettings\org\gnome\meld` and create the string value.